# Google App Engine. Channel API. The provided token is invalid.

Tags: google-app-engine, webrtc, channel-api, rtc

I've been trying to make an application for calling browser to browser using `WebRTC`. I wrote a simple servlet for creating channel:

```
  PrefClubChannelServletServlet extends HttpServlet {
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {
    String channelKey = req.getParameter("userid");
    resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    ChannelService channelService = ChannelServiceFactory.getChannelService();
    String token = channelService.createChannel(channelKey);
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");
    resp.getWriter().println(token);
}
}
```

I've deployed it in Google App Engine.
In my web application I've got a page with Java script, similar to https://apprtc.appspot.com. In my code Caller calls `prepare(1)`, and Callee – prepare(0).

```
function prepare(ini) {
    initiator = ini;
    card = document.getElementById("card");
    localVideo = document.getElementById("localVideo");
    miniVideo = document.getElementById("miniVideo");
    remoteVideo = document.getElementById("remoteVideo");
    resetStatus();

    console.log("Try to get token");
    getToken();
}

function getToken() {
    var token;
    if (initiator) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = 'http://pref-club.appspot.com/prefclubchannelservlet?userid=GGGG';
        xhr.open('POST', url, true);

        // Specify that the body of the request contains form data
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type",
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        xhr.send(url);

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                token = xhr.responseText;
                console.log("token = " + token);
                document.getElementById("token").value = token;

                openChannel(token);
                doGetUserMedia();
            }
        };
    } else {
        token = document.getElementById("token").value;
        console.log("token = " + token);

        openChannel(token);
        doGetUserMedia();
    }
};
```

So, both Caller and Callee use the same token to open channel, and indeed  they open channel, got media and made  `RTCPeerConnection`

```
function openChannel(channelToken) {
    console.log("Opening channel.");
    var channel = new goog.appengine.Channel(channelToken);
    var handler = {
        'onopen': onChannelOpened,
        'onmessage': onChannelMessage,
        'onerror': onChannelError,
        'onclose': onChannelClosed
    };
    socket = channel.open(handler);
}
```

The main problem is that event handler `onChannelMessage` doesn't work. I don't see any S->C: in console log. Callee doesn't see offer by Caller.

Then, I refreshed my servlet, redeployed it, and discovered I can't open channel at all. While Opening channel I'm getting Uncaught Error:

> The provided token is invalid.

Comment: Not seeing any problem with the code that would explain why a refresh would create bad tokens.  Unless you are reusing expired tokens somehow... To debug, set a token outright *String channelKey="mykey"*.  Put a console message in onChannelOpened.